# AWS S3 Lifecycle rule not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

I have a problem about AWS S3 lifecycle that i set up is currently not working.
This is the lifecycle rule

[image]

[image]

When i check to the bucket object, the 2 file that i testing is still there
[image]

My bucket is default/standard non version bucket, anyone know what the problem is ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It can take hours or even few days for lifecycle to trigger.